# Google Speech API - recognizing base64 encoded audio

Tags: audio-recording, google-speech-api

I've been struggling with the Google Speech API for a while and would love some advice.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Record audio in the browser
2. Convert the recording to base64 and send to my server
3. On the server, call Google Speech API's syncRecognize function, passing in my base 64 encoded audio

I always receive an empty results object.

When I follow this [getting started tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/getting-started) though everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Any tips/ideas would be very much appreciated.

```
const Speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');
const SpeechV1beta1 = require('@google-cloud/speech/src/v1beta1')

module.exports = {

    syncRecognize: function(base64Encoding) {

       const speech = Speech();
       const speechV1beta1 = SpeechV1beta1();
       const client = speechV1beta1.speechClient();

       const body = {
           "config": {
               "encoding":"LINEAR16",
               "sampleRate":16000,
               "languageCode":"en-US"
           },
           "audio": {
              "content": base64Encoding
           }
       }

       return client.syncRecognize(body)
        .then((results) => {
            console.log('results', results) 
            return {transcription: results[0]};
        }).catch(function(error) {
            return {error: error};
        });;

    }
}
```

Comment: I've never tried doing this in a browser before, so I'm not sure.  Is there some way you can save the audio content data to a file, to make sure it's playable (and that it's LINEAR16 16kHz)?  Does the same code work if you give it a URI?  If so, it seems like the problem is with the audio "content".

Answer (score 3):

Probably what you are recording from the browser has not have those config parameters.

Another issue that I have encountered is that, for an audio duration of more than 5 seconds, timeout kicks in, and so far, I've not been able to effectively change the API deadline. This might also be your case.

To verify the metadata of the audio in my web app I use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/): I automatically save the files to storage and run `ffmpeg -i filename` in a script to retrieve samplerate, encoding, number of channels and duration.

Be aware that there are [audio length limits](https://cloud.google.com/speech/limits) for synchronous speech recognition requests. If you exceed them, I suggest you use the asynchronous method (or split the audio file into subfiles). In the former case, you will probably need to convert the audio encoding (luckily, FFmpeg can also do that for you :) ). In the latter case, you can use [SoX](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/) to split the audio on silences and process them separately.